importing biom "ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject"
While working on my project on jupyter notebook
!pip install numpy
!pip install biom-format
and
from biom import Table, load_table
gives me this error message.

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 4>()
2 import warnings
3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 from biom import Table, load_table
5 from skbio import TreeNode, read
7 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/biom/init.py:51, in 
2 r"""
3 Quick start
4 ===========
(...)
41
42 """
43 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
44 # Copyright (c) 2011-2020, The BIOM Format Development Team.
45 #
(...)
48 # The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
49 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
---> 51 from .table import Table
52 from .parse import parse_biom_table as parse_table, load_table, save_table
53 from .util import format_version, version
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/biom/table.py:196, in 
191 from biom.util import (get_biom_format_version_string,
192                        get_biom_format_url_string, flatten, natsort,
193                        prefer_self, index_list, H5PY_VLEN_STR,
194                        format_version)
195 from biom.err import errcheck
--> 196 from ._filter import _filter
197 from ._transform import _transform
198 from ._subsample import _subsample
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/biom/_filter.pyx:1, in init biom._filter()
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
I figure there is some compatibility issue, especially with the numpy package, but I cannot figure out exactly what needs to be done. I have tried to upgrade the numpy and reinstall the biome-format, but it does not work. Does anyone have a similar issue?

So you know, you should be using magic %pip install when executing an install command in a running Jupyter .ipynb. The exclamation point in conjunction with installs can lead to problems. The magic version of the install command insures that the installation occurs within the environment where the kernel is running and is the current best practice. See more about the modern %pip install command here.

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. On another related topic... In your post, I see  ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8..., and so I know Anaconda is involved. So that means at some point you chose that as your primary package manager and you should be sticking purely with Anaconda/conda for managing packages. And so you shouldn't be mixing in matching %pip in there. It should be %conda install ....

 So for numpy, that would be specifically executing %conda install conda-forge::numpy in a notebook, based on here (found by searching 'numpy Anaconda conda-forge' in my browser and using the magic install command. Once you start using Anaconda/conda, you only want to ever use %pip when there is no conda recipe. Otherwise you are going to cause yourselves headaches as your conda environments won't be robust or portable. The other thing is that Anacona/conda has abilities that pip install doesn't and so it can do things on levels of ...

 your system that %pip install cannot touch. So in general, you may have more success if you are installing your dependencies with conda anyway. And hopefully in this case. The command for biom-format can be adapted from here and that should give you compatible versions. If that doesn't help, find the repo for the biom-format and search the issues for errors like yours. Maybe include numpy in the search time even. That may give you some guidance. ... Minor thing but very helpful for those trying to help you: Please read ...

 here about using code formatting where it specifically says 'Use fenced code blocks '. Your commands and error output should be in the blocks such as that so we get the line breaks and formatting in a readable way.
